# JsonIgnore attribute not working on API Model web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

In my .net 6.0 web api (c#) i am using JsonIgnore attribute to hide a property from resulted json outpul but it seems to take no effect,

Model

```
 public class xyz
    {
        //[IgnoreDataMember]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string AppNo { get; set; }
        public int dpd { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int currency { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Action Method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetInfoAsync([FromQuery] string identifier)
    {
        var info= await GetInfo(identifier);
        return Ok(info);
    }
```

In resulted output , I still see AppNo

```
 {
  "appNo": "12xcv56",
  "dpd": 0,
  "email": test@xt.com,
  "address": "b 101 j CHSL,thane",
  "currency": 1
    }
```

I have also tried [IgnoreDataMember] but it does not take any effect. Is there any other setting which i need to take for this ?

I am using newtonsoft.json for [JsonIgnore] attribute.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're also using Newtonsoft to serialize the data? By default it's probably System.Text.Json.

Comment: Have a try with [this attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=net-7.0) (same name, but different namespace).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride verified , using from NewtonSoft.Json

Comment: @Saurabh, From dotnet core 3.1, the Json part is handled by the `System.Text.Json` and if you need the `Newtonsoft.Json`, you have to override in on the `ConfigureServices` in Startup as `services.AddController().AddNewtonsoftJson()`

Comment: @SathishGuruV installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson for this but property still visible in response

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Thanks, it worked using System.Text.Json.Serialization;